# How to split string on second character match in python?

Tags: python, string, split

I have my string in variable:

```
query = 'name=Alan age=23, name=Jake age=24'
```

how do I split my string on `name=Jake` instead of `name=Alan`?
Don't suggest `query.split(name=Alan)`, it won't work in my case.

I need something that will skip first `name` and continue searching for second, and then do split. So, how can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried splitting on commas and performing `lstrip` on the remaining string?

Comment: What is the exact output that you want?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I want output to be in this format:
name1 = query.split(1)
name2 = query.split(2)
name3 = ....

Comment: @EV3REST Can you write a sample output, like an actual string that demonstrates what you're looking for?

Comment: @Shrey I need to put names into variables like name1, name2, name3

Comment: Tell us what you want.  Once the code is run, `variable1` will be..., `variable2` will be...  Fill us in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `query.split(',')[1].split('name')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting on the comma and then on the spaces like so:

```
query = 'name=Alan age=23, name=Jake age=24'
query_split = [x.strip() for x in query.split(",")]
names = [a.split(" ")[0][5:] for a in query_split]
print(names)

['Alan', 'Jake']
```

With this you don't need multiple variables since all your names will be in the list `names`, you can reference them by `names[0]`, `names[1]` and so on for any given number of names.

Comment: i have more than 2 'names' in the string, so i need to skip n amount of characters, that's what I was asking.

Comment: @EV3REST Skip until you reach what? What's your expected output?

Comment: @EV3REST There, that should do it.

Comment: I need to have different names in different virables, and names count is more than 2

Comment: @EV3REST You don't need different variables and that works for any number of names. `names[0]` will be Alan, `names[1]` will be Jake and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
query = 'name=Alan age=23, name=Jake age=24'
names = [y.split(" ")[0][5:] for y in (x.strip() for x in query.split(","))]
print(names)
```

Output:

```
['Alan', 'Jake']
```